# onClick button add Focus in an input field but that input is invisible

Tags: javascript, jquery, input, focus

this is my demo:
https://jsfiddle.net/larico/7d3851uf/1/

When click to search icon, the search Field was opened, so then should be focus on input, for writing in the field without clicking in the search field.

I was trying with this code:

```
$('.search').click(function(){
    $('#gosearch').focus();
});
```

**but seems doesn't work.** 
how could I solve it,

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Since you have a transition you would need to use [`transitionend`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/Events/transitionend):

```
$('.search').click(function(){ 
  $(this).toggleClass('opened');
  $('.big-search').toggleClass('displayed').one('transitionend', function(){
     $('#gosearch').click().focus()
  });
});
```

You can [see it here](https://jsfiddle.net/akrion/7d3851uf/14/)